# Time Scheduling - Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping, scrapyd

In Scarpy is there any way to schedule our spider to run on some time?

Comment: In which OS are you working? (win, Unix, Mac)

Comment: Suree, you run it from cron or task scheduler.

Comment: Am using ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I used the time delay { time.sleep(120) } in that but some time it was time out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `/etc/crontab` file and add this line

```
00     *     *   *    *        cd /path/to/scrapy/poject;scrapy crawl spider-name
```